# Harper-Hofstadter model in symmetric gauge

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, tight-binding

If I have l a square lattice, with the total flux = $\pi$, I can work in the symmetric gauge, which will have my vector potential be $A = \frac{\pi}{2}(-y,x)$.  In a tight-binding model with Peirels substitution, I can put it this way (J=1, let m be x direction, n be y):

$$H = \sum_{m,n}e^{-i\pi n/2}a_{m+1,n}^\dagger a_{m,n}+e^{i \pi m/2}a_{m,n+1}^\dagger a_{m,n} + HC$$

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of this under the Bloch theorem (kind of following along with [chapter 2, around 2.33](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/18148/1/Aidelsburger_Monika.pdf). Since I am looking at a phase of $\pi$, then with the Harper terminology, I have $\alpha = 2\pi \Phi \rightarrow\alpha = p/q = 1/2$ So I should have 2 subbands with individual Chern numbers not equal to 0 (I think).

$$\Psi_{m,n}=e^{iq_x m+iq_y n}\psi_n$$
Trying to plug it in:
$$e^{-i\pi n/2} a_{m+1,n}^\dagger a_{m,n}\Psi_{m,n}=e^{-i\pi n/2+iq_x}\Psi_{n,m}$$

Which all together ends up saying 
$$E\Psi_{n,m} = 2 \cos(q_x-\pi n/2)+2cos(q_y+\pi m/2)$$
From here, I do not see how 2 subbands would appear, as I now have a dependence on both m and n instead of a single index.

Comment: I don't understand your notation for your ansatz. What is $\Psi_{mn}$? What is $\psi_n$? Are $m,n$ indices that you sum over, or not?

Comment: The sum should indeed not be there.  But even in that case, I am unsure how to treat the n,m indices.

Comment: So you are assuming a plane-wave solution in the x direction? Is that justified?

Comment: Hm.  So the bloch ansatz is no good with the potential, however there should be some new symmetry in the form of magnetic translation operators mentioned in the link.